# Is there an adaptor available from Reactor Flux or RxJava2 Observable/Flowable to AkkaStreams Source?

Tags: akka, rx-java, project-reactor, akka-stream, reactor

Sometimes there are libraries, like R2DBC, which return a Reactive Stream, namely Reactor Flux, but then in the Http layer we need another Reactive Stream, namely AkkaStreams Source, which AkkaHttp knows and creates a streaming scenario with the http client useful for constant memory processing.

What is the manner to convert between reactive stream implementations? Are there adapter libraries available?

Comment: I've already posted links to the official AkkaStreams library which has a dedicated section about interoperability: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/reactive-streams-interop.html. Why do you keep asking for libraries/documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both libraries (Reactor & AkkaStreams) have the possibility of converting between their types (Source, Flowable/Observable) and the Publisher type existing in Java 9 which provides inter-operability. For instance
`Source.fromPublisher(r2dbc.query().asPublisher()` or something to that effect.